# Why do PD charging ports sometimes only support 65 watts and above devices (but not devices with less than 65 watts)?

Tags: laptop, battery, charging, thunderbolt, usb-pd

E.g., this laptop's specifications [state](https://us-store.msi.com/GS76-Stealth-11UH-078?search=%2011UH-078) ([mirror](https://archive.ph/av1GV)) (MSI GS76 laptop):

> PD charging port only supports 65W watts and above devices (e.g. adapter, powerbank).

Why do PD charging ports sometimes only support 65 watts and above devices (but not devices with less than 65 watts)?

Comment: I'd guess they expect that less beefy power supply won't keep up with charging the system under full load. They would rather not charge at all than slowly discharge the laptop despite it being plugged in (in certain conditions).

Comment: @gronostaj thanks,  why would they rather not charge at all than slowly discharge the laptop? Wouldn't slowly discharging make the battery last longer?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I think they don't want the laptop to behave in unexpected ways. Average user assumes that laptop plugged in = laptop charging. Realizing that battery is partially discharged or even empty after an intense gaming session is an unexpected surprise that are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

USB Power Delivery (USB-PD) specifications have evolved over the years,
and not all specifications are backward-compatible.

You may read about the different specifications in Wikipedia
[USB Power Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery).

Below is the table that is found in this article, which can show
the differences between specifications:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, interesting I don't see any threshold at 65 watts.

Comment: It's probably in the 60-100 segment. The port may be unreliable for less than 65W, or they wanted to play it safe.